# JavaScript - Retrieving data from firebase is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem right now with my app using Firebase. Somehow the path that I'm using is not working well.

Vacunas database not working:

[image]

This is my database on firebase.

I want to check if the number that the user introduced exists on the database. Somehow this code is not working, it is not doing the rootRefVerification.on('value',... I don't understand why.

```
$("#buscar_vacuna").click(

    function(){

        var numero_buscar = $("#numero_buscar").val();

        var rootRefVerificacion = firebase.database().ref('vacunas');

        var existencia2;

         //busqueda de numero de animal para saber si existe
        rootRefVerificacion.on('value', function(snapshot){
            existencia2 = snapshot.child(numero_buscar).exists();
        })

        console.log(existencia2);

        if(numero_buscar == ""){
            $("#numero_buscar").addClass("is-invalid");
            $('#detalles').slideUp(1000);
        }else if(existencia2 == false){
            alert('Animal ' + numero_buscar + ' no tiene vacunas');
            $("#numero_buscar").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#numero_buscar").val('');
            $('#detalles').slideUp(1000);
        }else{
```

I think is something with the path because when I changed the path from `'vacunas'` to `'inventario'` (check image below to see that) it works well.

Inventario database working well:

[image]

Hope someone can help me please.

Comment: the callback to `rootRefVerificacion.on` is called asynchronously - so `console.log(existencia2);` will always output 0 because nothing can change it (yet)

Comment: Please add `Inventario` code also..!

Comment: Your code uses `ref("vacunas")`, but your JSON shows `Inventario`. Code and JSON must match, so `ref("Inventario")`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Notice that OP posted his JSON twice. The first 1 shows `vacunas` and the second shows `Inventario`. OP said it only works on the latter scenario.

Comment: two things have tried to console `snapshot` returned from `rootRefVerificacion` using `on` function also if `numero_buscar` is empty like you have checked in your code it returns false.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think this is happening. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Himanshu When I tried to check the value from 'existencia2' with console inside the rootRefVerificacion.on it shows me the correct value. On the other side, when I check it outside from rootRefVerificacion.on is 0.

Comment: that's how asynchronous code works - asynchronously - try putting all the code from the console.log to the end, inside the callback, `rootRefVerificacion.on('value', function(snapshot){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback in `rootRefVerificacion.on('value', function(snapshot){` gets called asynchronously, so your code is essentially trying to get the value of `snapshot.child(numero_buscar).exists();` before it exists

simply move your code inside the callback

```
$("#buscar_vacuna").click(

function(){

    var numero_buscar = $("#numero_buscar").val();

    var rootRefVerificacion = firebase.database().ref('vacunas');

    var existencia2 = 0

     //busqueda de numero de animal para saber si existe
    rootRefVerificacion.on('value', function(snapshot){
        existencia2 = snapshot.child(numero_buscar).exists();
        console.log(existencia2);

        if(numero_buscar == ""){
            $("#numero_buscar").addClass("is-invalid");
            $('#detalles').slideUp(1000);
        }else if(existencia2 == false){
            alert('Animal ' + numero_buscar + ' no tiene vacunas');
            $("#numero_buscar").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#numero_buscar").val('');
            $('#detalles').slideUp(1000);
        }else{
    });
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you. But why, using the code that I posted, it worked with just a change of path from 'vacunas' to 'inventario'?

Answer (score -1):

You are using it incorrect. You are initializing `existencia2` with integer 0 but in your code you are assigning it a boolean value returned using exists. Please change this part of code.

```
     //busqueda de numero de animal para saber si existe
    rootRefVerificacion.on('value').then(snapshot => {
        existencia2 = snapshot.child(numero_buscar).exists();
        if(numero_buscar == ""){
            $("#numero_buscar").addClass("is-invalid");
            $('#detalles').slideUp(1000);
        }else if(existencia2 == false){
            alert('Animal ' + numero_buscar + ' no tiene vacunas');
            $("#numero_buscar").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#numero_buscar").val('');
            $('#detalles').slideUp(1000);
        }
    })
```

check this out for handling the code asynchronously using [promises](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html)

Comment: I have edited the code initialized `existencia2` to false for default. if snapshot exists. It will set to true

Comment: yes One can use promises returned by firebase using `.then`. and use your code to initialize values in `then` for making it asynchronous